# what happens with a process tasks after it is killed?

Tags: linux, kill, kill-process

When I kill (via shell) a process in Linux are the tasks in `/proc/pid/tasks` also killed immediately? Or can they run without the principal process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, each entry in /proc/pid/tasks is a thread in a process. Check [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/481268/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-threads-running-in-a-process-from-proc-pid-stat-i). So when you kill a process, all threads should be killed immediately.